# Extra argument 'method' in call using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying make a request with Alamofire but the errors occurs in parameterer `method: HTTPMethod`, I used the suggestive parameter `.post`.

`Alamofire.request(OdooAuth.host2!, method: .post, parameters: [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [])`

The host is ok because if I try the other way like:

`AlamofireXMLRPC.request(OdooAuth.host2!, methodName: "execute_kw", parameters: params)`
This works.

The problem is that I want use JSON instead XML.

Error in XCode:

[image]

I've searched in many posts on the web, Github, Stackoverflow, but the problems similars not have answer or not solves my problem.

Comment: Headers should be a dictionary `[:]` not an array `[]`, this is why the method signature doesn't match

Comment: Try this : `let _headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
        Alamofire.request(url as URL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: _headers).responseJSON { response in
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
let _headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"] 
Alamofire.request(url as URL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: _headers).responseJSON { response in 
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSONStandard

        if (jsonData != nil) {
            let jsonData = response as! Dictionary // PARSE AS PER RESPONSE
        } else {
            print("No Data")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: should use lowerCamelCase for variable names. What if the response is an array?

Comment: @Scriptable Replaced variable Name. I already write comment after `let JSONData = response as! Dictionary` **// PARSE AS PER RESPONSE**

Comment: @Augusto, Currently I used this code and it works fine. Try to update you `Alamofire` pod.

Comment: I found the error, my parameter `params` is wrong, I tried this: `Alamofire.request(OdooAuth.host2!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: _headers)` and has been compiled!

Comment: But I don't known how I can use this, because params expected by server is like: `var params = [OdooAuth.db, OdooAuth.uid, OdooAuth.password!,"product.template","search_read",[[]],[]] as [Any]` and parameter `params` must be `[String:Any]`

Comment: It not necessary that `params` must be `[String:Any]`. Also It can be `[String:String]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181281/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-augusto).

Answer (score 0):

Headers should be a dictionary `[:]` not an array `[]`, this is why the method signature doesn't match.

try

```
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in 
    // handle the response here
}
```

Comment: if (on a new line) you type `Alamofire.request(` do you not get any autofill with the same params? I dont have a project loaded with Alamofire atm to test

Comment: Yes, the autofill not works too, this is the problem.